# Route 53 health checking an FTP server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, failover, amazon-route53

We would like to use a TCP health check on port 21 for Route 53 failover of a pair of FTP servers running on EC2 instances with Elastic IPs.

The problem is that we have the FTP servers in a security group that only allows connections from a small whitelist of CIDR blocks (FTP is bad enough, but wide-open FTP is scary).

The security group is blocking connections from Route 53's health checkers.  I know that there are ways to poll for the current list of health checkers and you could theoretically update your security group accordingly, but that seems pretty hacky.

So I even tried building a little HTTP status page via PHP, which would connect to port 21 (and could theoretically even transfer a file to make sure everything is working).  I figured I could have Route 53 hit this status page (which unfortunately would have to be open to the world, but that's still better than leaving an FTP server wide open).

Since I don't know the IP address of the EC2 instance ahead of time, I'm configuring the security group to allow connections from all hosts within the security group.

But apparently, if you try to connect to an Elastic IP address, the security group settings don't translate (which kind of makes sense, but it blows my approach out the window).

So I'm starting to run out of ideas.  Anybody have any good approaches for dealing with the general problem of TCP health checks on an instance that limits access by CIDR block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracking the history of the [AWS published IP Ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) from 2015-07 (the earliest snapshot I have in the system I queried below) through 2017-03 (the latest I have) -- a period of over a year and a half -- you find that there have been exactly **zero changes** to the IPv4 address ranges for the Route 53 health checkers.

White listing these in your security group seems a perfectly reasonable strategy.

There are two small blocks of IPv4 addresses allocated for the purpose of originating health checks, in each of the 8 regions from which Route 53 can source checks.  (Route 53 doesn't originate checks from all of the AWS regions).

For each region that is testing your endpoint (the default is for all of them to test your endpoint) your health check will be associated with one checker in each block from each of regions... and when you look at the "Health checkers" in the console, you can see the results reported by the checkers, individually, including the checker's IP address (which will also of course appear in the server logs).

This is an extract of the relevant values:

```
+-------------------+----------------+
| ip_prefix         | region         |
+-------------------+----------------+
| 54.183.255.128/26 | us-west-1      |
| 54.228.16.0/26    | eu-west-1      |
| 54.232.40.64/26   | sa-east-1      |
| 54.241.32.64/26   | us-west-1      |
| 54.243.31.192/26  | us-east-1      |
| 54.244.52.192/26  | us-west-2      |
| 54.245.168.0/26   | us-west-2      |
| 54.248.220.0/26   | ap-northeast-1 |
| 54.250.253.192/26 | ap-northeast-1 |
| 54.251.31.128/26  | ap-southeast-1 |
| 54.252.79.128/26  | ap-southeast-2 |
| 54.252.254.192/26 | ap-southeast-2 |
| 54.255.254.192/26 | ap-southeast-1 |
| 107.23.255.0/26   | us-east-1      |
| 176.34.159.192/26 | eu-west-1      |
| 177.71.207.128/26 | sa-east-1      |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

I have not had a reason to track the IPv6 side, so I can't say conclusively that the same is true, but it stands to reason that the same situation will apply, there, as well.

Comment: Great information, Michael.  Thank you!  I will whitelist, and then if I get an "unhealthy" every couple of years, I can check for changes to the IP ranges (I'll just have to document that in my terraform code, since that probably won't be the first thing I will think of!)

Comment: Thanks @JasonPriebe.  I've updated to include something I overlooked -- you'll be assigned a checker from each of the subnets, and you can see the addresses in the console... so even if one block in a region were to change for whatever reason, it should be apparent from the Route 53 console that it could be security group related, because one checker would pass and the other would fail, and you can actually see the addresses Route 53 is currently checking you from.  The individual checker, I assume, can change, but it should be replaced with another one in the same block if that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a service like dyn-dns to provide static naming to the dynamic addresses. Every time the host is activated on a new IP the agent running in the session will update the dyn-DNS server with the correct Dynamic address.

We have found that this increases the reconnection rates of some of our end point vpn mappings.